# Is there no return value in the result of a transaction using ethersjs?

Tags: ethers.js, return

The Solidity example code :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract Test {
  uint256 testvalue;

  function testFunc(uint amount) public returns(uint) {
    testvalue = testvalue + amount;
    return testvalue; // read return data
  }
}
```

etherjs example code :

```
const TEST = await ethers.getContractAt("Test",address)

const tx = await TEST.testFunc(5);
const result_tx = await tx.wait()
```

The testFunc function has a return. But there is no value for return on successfully completed transaction with ethers. Is it like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this related question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71254497/documentation-for-ethers-getcontractat#:~:text=The%20getContractAt()%20function%20is,not%20included%20in%20their%20documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71254497/documentation-for-ethers-getcontractat#:%7E:text=The%20getContractAt()%20function%20is,not%20included%20in%20their%20documentation).

This is a hardhat ethers only extension, looks like you need to provide a signer or its a read-only contract. Since your function attempts to mutate `testvalue`, my guess is that it will not be a successful transaction.

https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-ethers#helpers